# Adding only 5 positive numbers

Tags: java

So the problem is when I hit run it goes well, but when I put 5 positive numbers then it would supposed to add them up but the sum is always 0. I don't know why, and if you put a negative value only the positive value will be added and will just ignore the negative value.

I did this on c++, it worked. But I can't seems to make it work on java.

**Example:**

Input : 1,1,1,-1,1

Output : 4 (it ignored the negative value)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] num = new int[5];
        int z;
        System.out.println("Enter only 5 positive numbers");       
         for(z = 0; z < 5; z++)
        {
            num[z] = n.nextInt();
        }
        int sum = 0;
        for(z = 0; z < 5; z++)
        {
            if(num[z] <= 0)
            {
                sum += num[z];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: look closer at `if(num[z] <= 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You are adding negative numbers in your code `if(num[z] <= 0)` this means if condition only runs if `num[z]` is less than or equal to `0`. Change `if(num[z] <= 0)` to this `if(num[z] >= 0)`

Answer (score 2):

In your code by `if(num[z] <= 0)` condition you are ignoring Positive numbers and adding only negative numbers.

Rather this condition should be updated to `if(num[z] >= 0)` to make it work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

problem is your if condition.use `if(num[z] >= 0)`.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] num = new int[5];
        int z;
        System.out.println("Enter only 5 positive numbers");
        for(z = 0; z < 5; z++)
        {
            num[z] = n.nextInt();
        }
        int sum = 0;
        for(z = 0; z < 5; z++)
        {
            if(num[z] >= 0)
            {

                sum += num[z];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `if(num[z] >= 0)` instead `if(num[z] <= 0)` if you want to sum up positive numbers.
The example you have mentioned should give you -1 sum with current logic.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `if(num[z] <= 0)` to `if(num[z] >= 0)` so it sums all the numbers bigger than 0. Else, like all positives are bigger than 0 no positive will be added.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);

    int range = 5;
    int[] num = new int[range];
    int z;
    System.out.println("Enter only 5 positive numbers");
    for(z = 0; z < range; z++)
     {
        num[z] = n.nextInt();
     }
    int sum = 0;
    for(z = 0; z < range; z++)
     {
        // CHANGED to sum the numbers bigger than 0
        if(num[z] >= 0)
         {
            sum += num[z];
         }
     }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the problem is in the `if` condition used for adding the numbers. `if(num[z]<=0)` change this condition as `if(num[z]>=0`.